# Indice del enlace con jquery

Tags: jquery

Supongamos que a lo largo del dom tengo varios enlaces con una misma clase, como puedo saber el indice que es ese enlace al hacer click.

```
<a href="#seccion" class="section-modchooser-link"></a> // Este seria el indice 0
<a href="#ejemplo" class="section-modchooser-link"></a> // Este seria el indice 1
<a href="#otro-ejemplo" class="section-modchooser-link"></a> // Este seria el indice 2


$('a.section-modchooser-link').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var clicked = $(this)
})
```

Lo que busco: si en el enlace 1 hago click, saber que ese enlace dentro del dom es el numero 1

Comment: Hola César. ¿Qué has probado? Qué errores tuviste?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info.   Un saludo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El método `$.index()` devuelve el índice del elemento en jQuery.

```js
$('a.section-modchooser-link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var clicked = $(this).index();
  console.log(clicked)
})
```

```html
<a href="#1" class="section-modchooser-link">1</a>
<a href="#2" class="section-modchooser-link">2</a>
<a href="#3" class="section-modchooser-link">3</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero es mejor esperar a que el autor clarifique sobre todo qué ha intetnado y qué le falló para poder ayudarle con sus errores y no con sus tareas. un saludo

Comment: Gracias, era justo lo que buscaba!

Comment: @CésarAlejandroM la proxima vez has de *buscar* mejor ya que poniendo *"indice jquery"* en google, el primer resultado es la respuesta...